# Read comma seperated csv to multiple arrays in php

Tags: php

sorry, not deep into php, couldn't find a hint.
A lot of files like this simplified example with name, age, are read per line:

```
adrian,44
bella,36
caesar,28
damian,22
...

$thatlist = array_map('str_getcsv', file('somedata.txt'));
```

Data is processed by looping through this 2d-arrays, sometimes seperating it into lists, exploding and so on. For future work it would be easier to read the data fields into seperate arrays.

Instead of **$thatlist[name][age]** it would preferably be **$name[]** and **age[]**
for each line of the file.
How can this be done in php? Or is there an easy way to split the columns into seperate arrays? Didn't find that either.
Thank you!

Comment: `$name = array_column($thatlist, 0); $age = ...`

Comment: Thank you, can't imagine how i missed that!